# RDS Cluster is identified as DocumentDB cluster when listing DocumentDB cluster via API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-documentdb

I have a RDS database cluster with 1 instance and no DocumentDB cluster. But when I tried to list the DocumentDB cluster via API, such as

```
AmazonDocDB docdb= AmazonDocDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
for(DBCluster db : docdb.describeDBClusters(new DescribeDBClustersRequest()).getDBClusters()) {
    System.out.println(db);
}
```

it will return the information of the RDS database cluster, which is wrong in my opinion. The question is how can I list DocumentDB cluster without showing the RDS database cluster (which in this case would be none)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consider review the [javadocs of the `describeDBClusters` method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/docdb/AmazonDocDB.html#describeDBClusters-com.amazonaws.services.docdb.model.DescribeDBClustersRequest-):

> Returns information about provisioned Amazon DocumentDB clusters. This API operation supports pagination. For certain management features such as cluster and instance lifecycle management, Amazon DocumentDB leverages operational technology that is shared with Amazon RDS and Amazon Neptune. Use the `filterName=engine,Values=docdb` filter parameter to return only Amazon DocumentDB clusters.

I assume, although it is unclear in the [javadocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/docdb/model/DescribeDBClustersRequest.html#withFilters-java.util.Collection-) and the [API description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/API_DescribeDBClusters.html), that you can provide the required filter in your `DescribeDBClustersRequest` with something like:

```java
AmazonDocDB docdb= AmazonDocDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
Filter filter = new Filter()
  .withName("engine")
  .withValues("docdb");
DescribeDBClustersRequest request = new DescribeDBClustersRequest()
  .withFilters(filter);
for(DBCluster db : docdb.describeDBClusters(request).getDBClusters()) {
    System.out.println(db);
}
```